# How do I backup media, game data (internal storage) using TWRP?

Tags: twrp

It is known that TWRP does not back up `/data/media` as you can read
[here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176441/131553) and on other posts on this site, also on [TWRP FAQ](https://twrp.me/faq/datamedia.html)

**How can one bypass this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an app that's just been released (tested on Moto X Play) that bridges the gap between Nandroid and **full** backup and backs up photos, videos, game data etc, which wasn't possible earlier

[Tipatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kdrag0n.tipatch) (Play Store) and quoting from [developers XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-twrp-tipatch-backup-internal-t3831217)

> Tipatch patches TWRP to backup contents of internal storage (emulated SD card) as part of Data, thus preventing data loss. Internal storage typically includes items such as photos, videos, downloads, game data, and other assorted files.
>
> A side effect is that wiping "Data" will also wipe internal storage. This cannot be fixed.

Programs (instead of using app) for all OS's available on [Github](https://github.com/kdrag0n/tipatch/releases)

I am not affiliated in any way with the app or developer and wanted to share a tip-off from a friend

Edit: Also now tracker free version [available in Izzy's F-droid repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.kdrag0n.tipatch)

**Edit 2** User [alecxs](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/170470/alecxs) who is a regular contributor here has a universal bind mount enabler, for the same functionality. You can download it from [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/recovery-fix-backup-internal-storage-t3941108). There is also a Magisk module "TWRP helper" that claims to do the same (not tested by me).

Answer (score 1):

I would follow the idea from https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/tutorial-create-internal-storage-backup-t3389172 - that is

> Step 1- reboot in recovery
>   Step 2-mount all partitions
>   Step 3-now open file manager
>   Step 4-go to path /data/media
>   Step 5-now rename media folder name to xyz
>   (now path name is /data/xyz)
>   Step 6- now go to backup window
>   Step 7- now refresh memory.... u notice that data partition memory is increase (data+internal storage)

and then back up to your preferred location, e.g. external SD card.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from TWRP version 3.4.0+ we can now make backup of Internal Storage straight from menu without any modification

thanks to the developers who finally decided to include that option after a long period of such feature request :)

Comment: Can you share where did you get that info? I'm struggling to find any info on it

Comment: @CaldeiraG see entry *"Internal Storage"* in [recovery.fstab](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_xiaomi_beryllium/blob/android-9.0/recovery.fstab) it is using *fsflags="bind"*

Comment: Ok, I see it but if I updated my TWRP now to the 3.4 version, would it work? I'm running a Redmi 5 Plus (vince)

Comment: @CaldeiraG unfortunately the maintainer (from Hubei Wuhan) is busy or not available, but you can add entry in twrp.fstab yourself