# Data Transfer to New Phone using TWRP

Tags: twrp

Fairly easy question. I have a Samsung S3 GT-i9305 LTE rooted, Android 4.4.4. sadly it's coming to the end of its life and its time to upgrade to a phone with a much newer OS (Android 8+). I have a full TWRP backup of my current phone. In principle, can anybody tell me if it's possible to use this backup to restore all my data to a new phone - (it will be a Samsung device of some type). I understand how to root and install TWRP on devices. I'm only asking the question as I cannot find the answer to this rather obvious situation which many people must encounter anywhere. I'm not at all bothered about transferring the apps as they will probably function better as fresh installations on the new device. I also use Titanium backup.

TIA people.

Tim Smith

Comment: You seem to be assuming that your TWRP will work on the new device. Almost certainly not (though) reverse is more likely. Restoring apps + app data with Titanium (TiBu) is a better idea rather than TWRP . So what data is left?1. `/data/media` isn't backed up by TWRP by default unless your TWRP supports [this method](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713/131553) 2. SMS and call records can be backed up TiBu or other apps. Other data like your important files and media etc are better backed up to PC or extSD and restored. IMO, that's better

Comment: TWRP and Titanium backup need root for making and restoring backup. Hence do you really want to root your brand new phone and directly loose guarantee? Therefore IMHO the recommended way is to use `adb backup` (respectively Helium backup) and backup all apps individually (that allow so). Also the Samsung own backup/migration tools have to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

A TWRP backup would be useless if not for your model only.... You can't restore a backup of a different Model on a different one even thou it's the Same Make.. So I guess the only options are listed above... Titanium backup is really Good for backing up of apps and data...

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the delay in replying. Titanium BACKUP. Yes, that's the best route I think, although whether TouchWiz would restore on a different Samsung phone remains to be seen. As far as routing a new phone is concerned, I never buy new kit, and so that is not an issue. I will also check out the compatibility of Helium and ADB. My main issue with data restoration is actually the desktop screen itself where I have a large number of internet links I would like to preserve.I'll save them to a bookmarks list in a browser, that should be fairly easy if a little time consuming.