# How do I backup Internal Storage to PC or OTG Drive without it changing folder and file modified dates?

Tags: backup, internal-storage, usb-on-the-go, internal-sd, date-and-time

I'm on Android 11 and I want to backup my files to a drive but I don't want it to change the modified date for folders and files...

Comment: Best way to preserve such attributes is packing all files into a TAR archive. You can create it via adb and directly save it on the PC: `adb exec-out 'cd /sdcard; tar -cf - .' > backup.tar`

Comment: what if i want to save it in a different drive? sorry i dont know a lot about adb..

Comment: What do you mean "different drive" as USB OTG stick or a drive on your PC?

Comment: portable ext hard drive, just start the command prompt where i want to save the tar?

Comment: An external hdd is fine. Just place the path before the `backup.tar` (specify an absolute path like `F:\backup.tar` on Windows.

Comment: after typing the command it makes a corrupted tar file that i cant open that's around 1kb....

Comment: `adb pull -a /sdcard` preserves *mtime*

Comment: @alecxs not for folders though...

Comment: Make sure you have `adb` installed on your PC, enabled on your phone and your phone connected via USB. Try `adb shell` first. if that works use the backup command. If that still does not work open the created file in an text editor and read the error message.

Comment: @Robert adb shell works. This is what the error message says /system/bin/sh: cd /storage/emulated/0: inaccessible or not found
/system/bin/sh:  tar -cf - .\: inaccessible or not found

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: cd /storage/emulated/0: inaccessible or not found
/system/bin/sh:  tar -cf - .\: inaccessible or not found
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I backup media, game data (internal storage) using TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/200713/how-do-i-backup-media-game-data-internal-storage-using-twrp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB pull stops after first error](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226573/adb-pull-stops-after-first-error)

Comment: How do I restore it directly to my phone after backing up using tar in your linked post