# How to install microg after LineageOS 18 upgrade

Tags: lineageos, micro-g

I understand the title sounds very basic. But I could not think of a way to describe my question in a short title. My question sort of comes in two parts. 1. Do I actually need to install microg and 2. Now that I have upgraded from LineageOS 17 with microg to LineageOS 18 without microg (by mistake), are there any gotchya's and clarify some instructions from [microg's official instructions](https://lineage.microg.org/#instructions).

Device is OnePlus 7 Pro, in case it matters. My particular case is, I recently upgraded from LOS 17 with microg to LOS 18 without microg by mistake. What I mean by that is, I'm still very green when it comes to flashing ROM's and other android development. I was more nervous about bricking my phone, I was following [Lineage's upgrade instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/guacamole/upgrade) to the tee. **Here is my mistake**. I used Lineage's upgrade instructions [link to the img to download](https://download.lineageos.org/guacamole) and flash, and not [microg's img download](https://download.lineage.microg.org/guacamole/) like I should have.

At first, I honestly didn't notice the difference at all. Microg's settings app was still installed, most apps seemed to work. They popped up a warning or notification about not being able to work without google play services, but allowed me to hit "**Ok**" and continue to use the app.

Just the other day, Lineage pushed out an OTA update, and I updated, then that changed. Now I can't use those apps at all anymore at all. They instantly close. So I went to searching for my issue, and basically it lead me to realize, I installed the LOS without microg. So I read their instructions to get an idea of what I should have done. Now I have questions.

**Question 1**: The symptoms I'm describing, I do actually need to re-flash the microg img even though I have the microg settings app installed. Correct? I think the answer is "**Yes**". I just want to see if anyone can confirm this or tell me maybe another or better way, since I'm dealing with a non-typical issue.

**Question 2**: If question 1 is "Yes" and I do need to re-flash with the microg lineage img. Then it's really a series of questions clarifying microg's installation instructions. Because I'm a newbie and don't understand everything as a more experienced android dev would.

- Do I or should I uninstall the microg settings app first?
- Since I just OTA updated, I think according to microg's install instructions, I need to wait for another release before trying to flash the microg lineage img, correct? Or would rolling back a version be a better option?
- In their *"Migration from LineageOS"* section, I noticed that they mentioned *"...you can't directely flash our ROM on top of the official LineageOS while keeping your data..."*. So I can't keep my personal data, or installed apps, pictures, music, etc? Is this correct? If so, is there any way to back it up, and re-install after I re-flash the microg img?
- In their install docs, they also say *"If you have installed unofficial builds of"*, and in that list, I think I have almost all of them. But I don't think they are *"unofficial"*. F-Droid should be from their github, and all the rest I think were installed from my last microg installation prior to the upgrade I just made. I honestly don't know if they technically still installed or not given my apps crashing which need google play services. As I mentioned the microg settings app is still there. I don't even know how to verify this. I will say, after having these troubles and poking around, I have noticed that they mention in the *"Post-install"* section that by default MozillaNlpBackend and NominatimNlpBackend are both plugins which are installed by default. And *"If you want to use these plugins, go to microG Settings -> UnifiedNlp Settings, configure and enable both"*. Even though I have the mocroG settings app installed. That *"UnifiedNlp Settings"* is just not there in mine.

So what do you guys think? Does it sound like this is my issue? That I don't have microg installed even though the settings app is there? And are there any special things I need to do before trying to re-flash the microg lineage img?

Comment: *"is there any way to back it up"* - main purpose of [TWRP](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200713)

Comment: Official LineageOS images are as far as I know always free of Google services because of license restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed/solved my problem/question(s). I wanted to follow up and answer my question in case it helps anyone else who comes across a similar situation. I will answer it in the manner I asked it. Then describe my exact steps.

1. Do I actually need to install microg? Yes
2. Now that I have upgraded from LineageOS 17 with microg to LineageOS 18 without microg (by mistake), are there any gotchya's and clarify some instructions from microg's official instructions? No

- Do I or should I uninstall the microg settings app first? No
- Do I need to wait for another release before trying to flash the microg lineage img? I'm not sure, but I did, and things worked flawlessly.
- Do I need to backup my personal data? No
- The NominatedNLP, I am still able to turn on, but I still seem to not be able to turn on the Mozilla Location Service. I might have to keep tinkering with this.

What I ended up doing?

- Waited for a new microG of LineageOS release. (Don't know if this is needed, it's just what I did)
- Connected my Android with `adb` and sideloaded the zip, just as [official instructions outline](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/guacamole/upgrade).

Once it rebooted, all things that required Google services are now working, and as far as I can tell, all apps are working just as expected, I'm able to make phone calls, no personal data is lost.

I hope this helps someone else.